# Add secret key to chart template

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm using HELM and I want to edit the 'deployment.yaml' file inside the 'templates' directory under a specific chart. But the content of the file looks like that:

```
{{- template "common.deployment" . -}}
```

How can I add a k8s secret key if I don't have the Containers spec section in this file and I don't want to edit the Common deployment?
should I copy the secret yaml from my k8s environment to a file at the 'templates' directory as well?

Comment: Did you try this: [Configmap and secrets](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/#configmap-and-secrets-utility-functions)?

Answer (score 0):

What you specify as `template "common.deployment" .` is defined in your `_helpers.tpl` file (or some other file with Helm kind-of macros). So you can edit it there.